# NRF24l01 receiving only zeros

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I want to transmit and receive data with the help of NRF24l01 modules. I tried to deliver joystick values from UNO to UNO but I have trouble about it.

In receiver side I have only zeros. I have been connect pins according to pin out orders.

```
ce--9
csn----10
sck----13
mosi----11
miso-----12
```

on both side. I am using module adapter to provide constant current and feeding with 3.3 volt and 5 volt another one. Both did not work. I bought new modules and adapters and connected 3.3 volt but nothing changed. I could not understand the problem help me please. Here is are my sketches:

**RECEIVER**

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;
RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);
int data[3];
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
}


void loop() {
  if ( radio.available() ) //Eğer sinyal algılarsan...
  {

    radio.read( &data, sizeof(data) );

    Serial.print("data[0]=");
    Serial.println(data[0]);
    Serial.print("data[1]=");
    Serial.println(data[1]);
    delay(300);
    radio.stopListening();

  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("no signal");
  }
}
```

**TRANSMITTER**

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#define PIN_ANALOG_X 0
#define PIN_ANALOG_Y 1
#define CE_PIN   9
#define CSN_PIN 10
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;
RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);
int data[2];

void setup() {

  // Start serial because we will observe values at serial monitor
SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
}

void loop() {

  // Print x axis values

  Serial.print("x: ");

  Serial.println(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_X));

  // Print y axis values

  Serial.print("y: ");

  Serial.println(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_Y));
  data [0] =map( analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_X),0,676,0,255);
  data [1] = map(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_Y),0,676,0,255);

 radio.write( &data, sizeof(data) );
  Serial.println("data0");
  Serial.println(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_X));
  Serial.println("data1");
  Serial.println(analogRead(PIN_ANALOG_Y));

Serial.println(data [0]);
Serial.println(data [1]);
  // Some delay to clearly observe your values on serial monitor.

  delay(300);

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to receive 3 ints at the receiver but you send 2 ints at the transmitter? Also why  `radio.stopListening();` after one packet is received?

Comment: Actually ı found some codes from internet and re-arrange them. At the begining codes that ı found were not containing  radio.stopListening(); command and also it was not working. I wrote it because of ı thought it could be problem but it did not work despite of it.
int data[2]; is a mistake and ı re-arranged it as int data[3];

Comment: But at the transmitter side you send a `int data[2]` array, so it also has to be the same at the receiver. I would also remove the `Serial.println("no signal");` in the receiver as to not spam the console. Do you then see any output in the receiver?

Comment: I delete the Serial.println("no signal"); and wrote int data [2] at both side but nothing has changed , at receiver side ı have still zeros

Comment: "Have zeroes" meaning it prints "data[0]=0 data[1]=0"?

Comment: yes at receiver's seril port screen ı have that;
data[0]=0;
data[1]=0;

Comment: So th data reception works, because `radio.available()` returned true and read the data. Are the source data at the transmitter also 0? How did you connect the transmitter to the joystick?

Comment: ı am using joystick shield v1.a. I am trying to transmit joystick values hence source data are not zero.There is a place to nrf24l01 and ı directly connected to this place but ı have also tried to connect into pins of shield with same configuration of receiver but nothing has been changed.

Comment: Again, what does the transmitter print when it sends data?

Comment: transmitter print joystick values as data[0]=329; and data[1]=335; but receiver prints data[0]=0; data[1]=0;